# TypeScript interface does not result in an error if property is initialized as null

Tags: typescript

As you can see, age is a number, and if I try to initialize it as something other than a number, it errors appropriately. However, if I initialize it as null and set it later, I get no errors from doSomething treating it as an object.

Shouldn't TypeScript be able to give an error for trying to set someProperty on this.age, which is a number? If not, why? Do I need to do something additional to tell TypeScript that this.age is a number?

```
interface MyServiceInterface {
  age: number;
  doSomething () : void;
}

function myService () : MyServiceInterface {
  return {
    age: null,
    doSomething: function () {
      this.age.someProperty = false;
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this doesn't give you a compile time error is because `this` is of type `any` in `doSomething`. TypeScript currently does not assume the type of `this` in all scenarios and there's no way to specify the type of `this` in a function; however, there is an open [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/229) to be able to do this.

I would suggest you change your code to use a class:

```
class MyService implements MyServiceInterface {
    age: number;

    doSomething() {
        this.age.someProperty = false; // error
    }
}
```

This code is more readable and better expresses the intent.

Alternatively you could change your existing function to:

```
function myService () : MyServiceInterface {
  return {
    age: null,
    doSomething: function () {
      var self = <MyServiceInterface> this;
      self.age.someProperty = false; // error
    }
  };
}
```

...which is annoying and makes developer error more likely.